# Chamada a um Rest WebService com um Pedido Post

Tags: android, web-service, rest, post, request

Eu queria fazer no Android, uma chamada a uma *Rest WCF WebService*, através de pedidos POST.

Em C# eu consigo, enviando o post, url e o `body param`.
Mas no *Android*, sempre que envio um parâmetro, o método webservice(apesar de eu me conseguir conectar), diz que os dados tão sempre inválidos.

O código que tenho até agora é este, que é o método principal de ligação:

```
public void LoginWS(final String urlWS, final String user) throws Exception 
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() 
            {
                try 
                {
                   //urlWS = "http://192.168.1.25/webservice/metodoPOST

                    String inputCoded = Base64.encodeToString(user.getBytes("UTF-8"), Base64.NO_WRAP);
                    HttpURLConnection request = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(urlWS).openConnection();

                    try {
                        request.setDoOutput(true);
                        request.setDoInput(true);
                        request.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                        request.setRequestMethod("POST");                        
                        request.connect();

                        InputStream is = request.getInputStream();
                        String resp = convertStreamToString(is);
                        byte[] data = Base64.decode(resp, Base64.NO_WRAP);
                        response = new String(data, "UTF-8");

                        is.close();


                    } finally {
                        request.disconnect();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        thread.start();
    }
```

Do lado do webservice em WCF Rest, a assinatura do método é o seguinte:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,      ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    string metodoPOST(string input);
```

Como faço para enviar um pedido POST sem enviar parametros com nome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Miguel, para enviar os dados você deve usar `OutputStream`. Então, tente usar o seguinte:

Troque:

```
InputStream is = request.getInputStream();
String resp = convertStreamToString(is);
byte[] data = Base64.decode(resp, Base64.NO_WRAP);
response = new String(data, "UTF-8");
```

Por:

```
OutputStream os = request.getOutPutStream();
os.write(user.getBytes());
os.flush();
os.close();
```

Para pegar o código de resposta:

```
int responseCode = request.getResponseCode();
```